# Is it possble for an argument string to not be enclosed in double quotes?

Tags: common-lisp

I wish to define something that takes a non-double-quoted "string" as an argument. For example:

```lisp
(f The quick brown fox.)  ; Returns: "The quick brown fox."
(f   The  quick  brown  fox.  )  ; Returns: "  The  quick  brown  fox.  "
(f [:case 'upper] The quick brown fox.)  ; Returns: "THE QUICK BROWN FOX."
(f [:caps 'lower]    The quick brown fox.   )  ; Returns: "   the quick brown fox.   "
(f [:caps 'lower :trim t]    The quick brown fox.   )  ; Returns: "the quick brown fox."
```

It seems that macros are not suitable for this task. Is the above actually possible in Common Lisp?

If it is possible, could you tell me what features of Common Lisp I will need to learn/use in order to achieve the above? I don't need to be given the solution; I just need someone to point me to the right direction.

If it is impossible, could you explain why?

Comment: @adabsurdum I'm just wondering if Common Lisp has this flexibility. The "string" argument (all the variants of `The quick brown fox.`) will always be literally there (i.e. explicitly given as an argument).

Comment: @adabsurdum Yes, `f` is only for typing convenience. Its arguments will not be programatically generated.

Comment: In **every** programming language, strings must be delimited in some way, in order for the parser to read them correctly. Otherwise, if you have a function that takes two strings, how do you separe its arguments? For instance, if `g` is a function that takes two strings, how do you interpret `(g these are two strings)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can hack the Lisp reader, up to the point where the syntax you want to use is possible. More precisely, you can hack the reader-macro associated with the open parenthesis to detect if the form starts with `(f ...`, in which case you parse the input stream as you wish, or else you defer reading to the existing reader.

This is however a hack that may not compose easily with other customizations to the readtable. A better solution would be to define a custom reader macro with [`SET-MACRO-CHARACTER`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_ma.htm), say `§(...)`, which reads a string until the closing parenthesis.

```
§(The quick brown fox.)
```

Or:

```
§[:caps 'lower :trim t](The quick brown fox.)
```

The above would be equivalent to a form like this, where `str` is a macro or function of your own:

```
(str "The quick brown fox." :caps 'lower :trim t)
```

But you have to be careful about corner cases.

For example, if you want to use a parenthesis in your string:

```
§(The quick (brown) fox.)
```

the above would be read as:

```
 "The quick (brown"
```

Since closing parentheses are used to stop reading a string, it cannot appear in the string itself. If that's not acceptable, you need to extend the syntax.

For example you need to define how to escape characters. Usually this means prefixing characters with backslash `#\`.

Also one possible advantage of this syntax is to be able to nest strings without having to escape double quotes (just like in bash were `$()` is a better syntax than backticks):

```
§(The quick §(brown) fox.)
```

Ideally this would be the same as:

```
 "The quick \"brown\" fox."
```

This means that now `#\§` is also a special character in your own mini-language.

That might work, and could be fun to implement, but is worth it? There is already a short syntax for writing strings, with double-quotes.

> f is only for typing convenience.

I mean it takes more characters to write `(f ...)` than `"..."`, and the case conversion etc. can be done with functions or macros with short names if you want.
Maybe you could start by defining the `str` form and see if that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

As coredump says the right approach to this is some kind of read-macro: you obviously can do whatever you want with the reader but you typically want to do things which don't foul up everything *else* too much.

The only useful case I can see for something like this (and I'm increasingly unsympathetic to 'I want to do this mad thing just because I can' ideas: syntax changes, especially read-syntax changes, should be useful) is to have some notion of a string reader which allows you to specify various operations on the string you read, such as trimming it.  I certainly can't see why anyone would want to type `(s ...)` instead of `"..."` otherwise.  I'm also not going to try to take over whatever the left-paren reader is because that definitely is going to make it very hard to meet the 'don't foul up everything *else* too much' criteria.  And finally, since I'm too lazy to write a delimited-string-reader (it's not hard but it can be mildly fiddly to get right), the below will actually read strings delimited by `#"...": that way I can just punt to the existing string reader for most of the work.

First of all assume a function `process-string` whose job is to massage some string based on keyword arguments.  Here's a version which just allows trimming:

```
(defun process-string (s &key (trim nil))
  (let ((ss s))
    (when trim
      (setf ss (string-trim '(#\Space #\Tab #\Newline) ss)))
    ss))
```

Now we'll not smash the standard readtable:

```
(defvar *silly-rt* (copy-readtable nil))
```

And we're going to define a reader which sits on `#"` (which is unused in the standard readtable) which will read strings with some options to do things to them.

But note that, because read-time is properly ahead of evaluation time, if we want to be able to control things at evaluation time, then this read macro needs to turn, not into a string, but into a form involving `process-string`, so that's what it will do.

- `#"xyz"` will read as `(process-string "xyz")`;
- `#"(:trim t) xyz "` will read as `(process-string " xyz " :trim t)`;
- `#"\(:trim t) xyz"` will read as `(process-string "(:trim t) xyz")` (you can escape the open paren to defang it);
- `#" (:trim t) xyz"` will read as `(process-string " (:trim t) xyz")` (the open paren needs to be the very first character).

Here is a function suitable for attaching to a dispatching read macro character which does this:

```
(defun read-silly-string (stream char prefix)
  (declare (ignore char prefix))
  (let ((controls (if (char= (peek-char nil stream t) #\()
                      (read stream t nil t)
                    '())))
    `(process-string ',(funcall (get-macro-character #\")
                                stream #\")
                     ,@controls)))
```

Notes.

- It simply peeks at the first character to know if there are any controls there.
- It learns how to read strings by calling whatever the normal string-reader is, simply by looking it up in the readtable.

Now we can glue this thing onto the readtable, and define a test function:

```
(set-dispatch-macro-character
 #\# #\"
 #'read-silly-string
 *silly-rt*)

(defun silly-read ()
  (let ((*readtable* *silly-rt*))
    (read)))
```

And now:

```
> (silly-read)
#""
(process-string '"")

> (silly-read)
#"(:trim t) x y"
(process-string '" x y" :trim t)

> (silly-read)
(let ((trim nil))
  #"(:trim trim) x y")
(let ((trim nil)) (process-string '" x y" :trim trim))

> (silly-read)
(let ((trim nil))
  #" (:trim trim) x y")
(let ((trim nil)) (process-string '" (:trim trim) x y"))
```